# How does Google Analytics track referring URLs?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

When a visitor clicks on a link or is redirected to my site from another site, Google typically includes information about the page the domain and the page the visitor was linked from.

How does Google track this information?

Answer (score 8):

I think, it uses the [document.referrer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) properties via Javascript. See the attached link!

Comment: It should also be noted that this property is blocked by some privacy plugins and, if the visitor came from a secured (SSL) site, the document.referrer property will not be populated.